# How to log into remote windows desktop server from linux mint?

Tags: xfreerdp

I need access a remote windows machine which I don't have any privilege on. The machine runs windows server 12R2, and the sys admin tells me that the RDP protocol there is the latest one. I tried to connect to the machine with xfreerdp and I get:

```
xfreerdp -u <username> <ip.address.of.machine>
connected to <ip.address.of.machine>
Password:
SSL_read: Failure in SSL library (protocol error?)
Authentication failure, check credentials.
If credentials are valid, the NTLMSSP implementation may be to blame.
```

The `username` and `password` are valid. I do have to mention that I was asked to write the `username` as `<uni-users>\<myusername>`. I read in several places that I need to disable `nla` security feature, which I don't think the sys admin will do. Is there a proper way to overcome this?

---

*Edit*

I can connect to the remote machine from a windows machine, here is the `rdp` definition fine

```
screen mode id:i:2
use multimon:i:0
desktopwidth:i:1920
desktopheight:i:1080
session bpp:i:32
winposstr:s:0,1,400,195,1200,795
compression:i:1
keyboardhook:i:2
audiocapturemode:i:0
videoplaybackmode:i:1
connection type:i:7
networkautodetect:i:1
bandwidthautodetect:i:1
displayconnectionbar:i:1
enableworkspacereconnect:i:0
disable wallpaper:i:0
allow font smoothing:i:0
allow desktop composition:i:0
disable full window drag:i:1
disable menu anims:i:1
disable themes:i:0
disable cursor setting:i:0
bitmapcachepersistenable:i:1
full address:s:<ip.address.of.machine>
audiomode:i:0
redirectprinters:i:1
redirectcomports:i:0
redirectsmartcards:i:1
redirectclipboard:i:1
redirectposdevices:i:0
autoreconnection enabled:i:1
authentication level:i:2
prompt for credentials:i:0
negotiate security layer:i:1
remoteapplicationmode:i:0
alternate shell:s:
shell working directory:s:
gatewayhostname:s:
gatewayusagemethod:i:4
gatewaycredentialssource:i:4
gatewayprofileusagemethod:i:0
promptcredentialonce:i:0
gatewaybrokeringtype:i:0
use redirection server name:i:0
rdgiskdcproxy:i:0
kdcproxyname:s:
drivestoredirect:s:
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe they publish RDP using a remote desktop gateway?

In this case you'll need to provide "/g:gateway" switch.

Comment: I can log easily from windows machine to the server, so I don't think that's the case. How do I use the tag or check if I need it or not?

Comment: If you already connect from windows client you should have something in advanced settings of saved RDP file.

Comment: I've edited my question, adding the ``rdp`` file content.

Comment: no, unless you edited lines from gatewayhostname you're definetely not using a remote desktop gateway. btw here's the way i use freerdp:

xfreerdp /v:RDP hostname /u:username /d:domain /p:password.

if you have strange characters in password remember to escape them \

Comment: Which OS, my machine doesn't accept this notation, only the regular ``-`` one

Comment: Can't check right now freerdp version, btw os is latest Debian

Comment: That's odd, I'm using Linux Mint 17.3.

Comment: xfreerdp /v:hostname /u:username /d:domain /p:password (escaping special chars with "\")

Sorry i previously wrote "/v:RDP hostname" that's not correct i'm not with my laptop so i copyed/pasted wrong.

Answer (score 1):

try `rdesktop` works just fine and is simple to use. When you want a GUI try `remmina`

Comment: The reason that I switched to ``xfreerdp`` was because this program would actually give information. ``rdesktop`` yields ``Error: recv: Connection reset by peer`` while ``remmina`` gives ``Unable to connect to RDP server <ip.address.of.machine>``